# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 12 (char 11)

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I send a json to a file that converts the it in three different values (files, path, myDict), then I parse `myDict` to json using dumps and I sent the string to `process.py`

In `process.py` in main function I read the string `myDict` and I try to convert in dict with loads but it gets an error
I've erased and spaces after : with replace but the loads function doesn't work... any idea?..... the column 11 is ":" I suppose

```
files = (json.loads(data))["archivo"]
path = (json.loads(data))["carpeta"]
myDict = (json.loads(data))["diccionario"]
myDict = json.dumps(myDict)
bashCommand = "python script.py "+files+" "+path+" "+myDict
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(),stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
######In main script.py the code is
inFilex = sys.argv[1]
outFol = os.path.join("/outputs", sys.argv[2])
cadena = sys.argv[3]
cadena = cadena.replace('\n','')
cadena = cadena.replace(": ",":")
dictA = json.loads(cadena)
#The string myDict
myDict = {"julDay": 47, "year": 18, "spacecraft_ID": "LANDSAT_8", "wrs_path": "19\n", "wrs_row": "47\n", "date_aquired_str": "2018-12-11"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved using separator=() in the dumps function

myDict = json.dumps(myDict, separators=(',',':'))

hope it will be useful